# Creating a Generic Method to Run Specific Methods as Parameters

Tags: java, java-7

I'm trying to change the brightness, contrast, and other values of an image. I'm finding that I'm using a classical double for-loop for a lot of these operations, and just running some simple math inside of the double loop, as shown below:

```
public void changeBrightness(int brightness)
{
        for(int i=0; i<height; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
            {
                pixels[j][i] = MathUtils.ensureRange(pixels[j][i] + brightness,0,254);
            }
        }
}
```

However, I now need to create a changeContrast method with almost the exact same form, and I'd like to make these operations pluggable with a little different math where the pixels are being set. So, I would like to create a generic method with the double for loops that will execute a method that is passed as an argument. How would I go about this in Java 7? Below is an example of what I'm thinking:

```
public void runPixelOperation(***pixel operation method goes here***)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<height; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
            {
                pixels[j][i] = ***run pixel operation here***
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Java 8 only?  Or early versions too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use an interface for this problem made for interfaces!

```
interface PixelLogic {
    public int doOperation();
}

class BlurLogic implements PixelLogic {
    @Override
    public int doOperation() {
        return // some calculated value
    }
}

class SomeClass {

    public void runPixelOperation(PixelLogic logic) {
        for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                pixels[j][i] = logic.doOperation();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface, say, `PixelOperation`, and declare one method.  That method can take one value that will be supplied from `pixels[j][j]` when it's called.

Have `runPixelOperation` take one parameter, an instance of `PixelOperation`.  Call that method, passing `pixels[j][i]`.

When `runPixelOperation` is called, the caller will pass a concrete instance of `PixelOperation`, as a subclass, an anonymous subclass, or a lambda expression.

```
runPixelOperation( (value) -> MathUtils.ensureRange(value + brightness,0,254) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what version of Java you are using, but this is the sort of thing Java lambdas were intended for.